# Excel Query - how to apply an IF statement to the last cell with a value in a row

Tags: excel

In excel, I am creating a tracker and I want to apply a status i.e. on track or overdue depending on the last cell in a row that has a value.

so in the first column stage 1, if a user inputs a value between 1-3, it will show as on track but if a user inputs 4 it will show overdue. In the next column stage 2, a user should input a value between 4-8 and but if they input 6 the status should show as on track (and disregard the previous overdue).

There will be multiple rows, each at a different stage in the process, so i would like the formula to check in each row where the last value is, check that against the appropriate range and return the appropriate status.

Hope this makes sense!

*Update screengrab attached. The numbers in the rows are entered by a user compared to the range in the top row. i.e. Day 4, when it should be between days 1 and 3.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlZpH.png)

Comment: Maybe a screenshot of your setup would be helpful here.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the below cell is empty for the entire row, then it will be true only in the last cell.

```
=IF(A2="",A1,"last cell")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this formula at the last. Based on your example, i have pasted it in Column D

```
=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,A2:C2)
```

See Image[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! what i'd then like to do is assign a status if the last value is in the assigned range outlined in the first row, i.e. for day 4-7, the value should be between 4 and 7, but it is 17, therefore the status should show as overdue if that makes sense!